# How to represent non-taxonomic relation in Owl

Tags: owl, ontology, relation

How to represent a non-taxonomic relationship between two concepts in OWL ontology language? 
For example:

Bank(concept1) ---- Offer(relation) ---> Credit (concept2)

Earth(concept1)---- is bigger than(relation) ---> Mercury (concept2)

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the [OWL standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/) for multiple examples. But imagine you want to write this in Manchester Syntax, you could have something like the following:

```
Class: Bank subClassOf: Offer some Credit
Class: Earth subClassOf: isBiggerThan min Mercury
```

However, I cannot stress enough, that most of these relations and their restrictions (`some`, `only` or ...) are strictly modelling decisions and you need to decide what works best based on what you need to model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Reading the standard OWL I found that the relationship can also be expressed by using the Domain and Range property. In your opinion, what is the difference?

Comment: In short,  a range or domain does not typically limit what can be used, but rather, provides information about what is used. So a better option in your case is to set restriction.